# nginx logging : first byte and last byte received

Tags: nginx, logging

I need to log all requests where nginx is taking huge time to respond to user. Upstream time is in 200 ms where nginx response time is > 333 secs
I would like nginx to log:

1. When it received first byte of the request
2. When it received last byte of the request
3. When it sent the request to upstream
4. When it got response from upstream

Comment: Have you looked into this article https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/ ?

Comment: Yes, didn't get my answer there. Do you have any suggestions from that site ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't played around with Nginx server logging. Found the link relevant so posted. Maybe starting a bounty will attract the relevant SO user to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom logging pattern by editing nginx config `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
log_format apm '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
           'method=$request_method request="$request" '
           'request_length=$request_length '
           'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
           'body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
           'referer=$http_referer '
           'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
           'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
           'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
           'request_time=$request_time '
           'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
           'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
           'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';
```

Here is a sample log format called apm that includes these four NGINX timing variables along with some other useful information, and update the access log to use that formatting

`access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log apm;`

To find the request which takes greater resonse time, you will have to send the data to ELK or similar service and filter it from there:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaFH2PcYI64&ab_channel=TravelsCode

You can create dashboard in kibana to get full picture of the results

**eg**: https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/04/02/setup-kibana-dashboards-for-nginx-log-data-to-understand-the-behavior/